# Is there a method to measure the change of normal distribution by the change of standard deviation over time?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a little problem and bother me quite a bit.
Say, I have a given data from a certain group at the period of *t = 1*.
This data follows a normal distribution with mean = $ \mu $ and sd = $ \sigma_1 $.

Then, I also have several data at the period *t = 2, 3, ..., T*
And each period data also follows normal distribution with sd = $ \sigma_2 $, $ \sigma_3 $, ..., $ \sigma_T $.

The problem I have:
"Can we measure the speed of change for the normal distribution from *t = 1* to *t = T*? Or, is there any method or generate a function to measure the change over time?

Thank you.

Comment: By speed of change do you mean $\frac{d\sigma}{dt}$?

Comment: @Paul Yes, the change of sigma over time. Let's say the distribution of data at t = 1, 2, ..., T. Should I make a function sigma over t to analyze this problem? Or should use the pdf function from the data at time t=1, 2, ..., T? Or, is there any other solution/method? I am sorry, I am not advanced in Statistics and English. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you have a set of $\sigma$ values over time can you simply plot $\sigma$ against t? The slope of this graph is the rate of change of $\sigma$, which may of course not be constant.

Comment: Thank you @Paul for the reply. The follow-up question is, If we have several groups then compare their $\sigma$ over $\t$? Besides the visual comparison.

Comment: Think the problem will need some context at this point. Maybe you could plot the groups of $\sigma$ data over time and ask a follow up question then? It is not obvious what you mean by compare and a graph might help.

Comment: Ah, I see. I understand now. Thank you very much for the advice. Seems sometimes a simple problem becomes "looks complex" due to a lack of focus.